# Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I've been following an Ionic tutorial made by a content creator named Paul Halliday. The project is a shopping list that uses Firebase and Angular.

My problem is that whenever I run the app, I receive an error that looks like the following:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

I've tried to look through other examples of how to fix my code, but none of them seem to comply with my code.

Currently, my page's Ts file is titled shopping.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavParams, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { AddShoppingPage } from '../addshopping/addshopping';

import { AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { ShoppingItem } from 'src/models/shopping-item/shopping-item.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-shopping',
  templateUrl: 'shopping.html'
})
export class ShoppingPage {
  
  shoppingListRef$: Observable<ShoppingItem[]>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
              public navParams: NavParams,
              private database: AngularFireDatabase
       ) {

         this.shoppingListRef$ = this.database.list('shopping-list').valueChanges();
  }

  navigate2AddShoppingPg() {
    this.navCtrl.push(AddShoppingPage);
  }  

}
```

There is also an interface that we have defined through a ts file:

```
export interface ShoppingItem {
itemName: string;
itemNumber: number;
}
```

Finally, the html of our shopping page is:

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Shopping List</ion-title>
  <ion-buttons end>
    <button (click)="navigate2AddShoppingPg()">
   <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
 </button>
  </ion-buttons> 
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

 <ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor = "let item of shoppingListRef$">
   <h2>Item Name: {{item.itemName}}</h2>
   <h3>Quantity: {{item.itemNumber}}</h3>
  </ion-item>
 </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

Any help would be super appreciated. Thank you!!

**Edit 2 ~~three months after~~**
I haven't visited this question in a while, but to avoid being misleading to those seeking a solution, yes, the async pipe is actually supported.

Comment: You are trying to execute an object in ngFor. ngFor only supports array. So you need to use objToArray concept with help of pipe I think

Comment: `shoppingListRef$` is an Observable, so it cannot be iterated with `*ngFor`, as it is not an array. However, it does emit an array, so you can add the `async` pipe, like so: `let item of shoppingListRef$ | async`

Comment: @PareshGami, thank you for the feedback! Unfortunately, I'm using version 5 of angular2, which means that the pipe async is no longer supported.

Comment: @caroline. Pipe is supporting

Comment: I was having a similar issue and used `async` pipe as suggested by @user184994 and that fixed it for me. This was on Angular 7 and Firebase 5.8.4 Thanks

Comment: @Mena check my edit from a couple months ago :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `shoppingListRef$` does not represent any iterable type for Angular. It's `Observable<ShoppingItem[]>`, whereas `Observable` by itself is uniterable. What you are trying to do is to iterate over value *returned* from the observable. Try something like below:

```
/* controller field */
listItems: ShoppingItem[] = [];

this.database.list('shopping-list').valueChanges()
.subscribe((v: ShoppingItem[]) => {
  this.listItems = v.slice(0);
})
```

And in template:

```
    <ion-item *ngFor = "let item of listItems">
        <h2>Item Name: {{item.itemName}}</h2>
        <h3>Quantity: {{item.itemNumber}}</h3>
    </ion-item>
```

And as mentioned by @user184994 you can as well use `async` on template, which basically under the hood will subscribe to observable and pass forward returned values.
One remark, if you wish your view to keep in sync with data, this component change detection strategy can *not* be set to `onPush`

Comment: I've switched the code to what you have suggested, but now I'm getting an error of this type: 

TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.project (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:84582:76)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:66366:27)...

Comment: try to run: `npm i rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 promise-polyfill --save`. However, your current error is not related with your base question. Base problem shall be resolved, now you have to struggle with rxjs up and running. If you copt-paste your error message to search engine, couple other stack topics directly address your issue